# Enable SSL in Tomcat SSL using Http11NioProtocol

Tags: java, tomcat

I have enabled SSL for my site using tomcat server.xml. However, when i go to chrome/IE there is always a warning that the site is "not secure". Refer the below snippet for the updates. How to ensure that users should not get the warning. Address of the site is https://35.200.235.243/compression/index.jsp

```
<Connector SSLEnabled="true" acceptCount="100" clientAuth="false"
        disableUploadTimeout="true" enableLookups="false" maxThreads="25"
            port="443" keystoreFile="/root/.keystore" keystorePass="password"
            protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" scheme="https"
                secure="true" sslProtocol="TLS" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Only you can trust a self-signed certificate. If you want one that is universally trusted, you'll need to buy one from an issuing authority. However, it appears that this particular certificate was issued for a different domain from the one that is being visited. FIx this, and you'll probably get another warning about trust.

The warning is because of the certificate you generated is not trusted by the browser.

To suppress this on *machines you control* you can add the certificate to the trusted root CA store ([Example](http://blogs.technet.com/b/sbs/archive/2007/04/10/installing-a-self-signed-certificate-as-a-trusted-root-ca-in-windows-vista.aspx)).

If this machine is on the internet/accessed by machines you do not control, you cannot alter this behavior unless you purchase a cert from a trusted issuing CA.

Comment: Is there any solution freely available

Comment: To be exact, that cert is issued for two _addresses_ neither of which is correct and one of which is not valid on the public net. An address is not a domain name, although a domain name _usually_ maps to one or more address(es). @ShailenderJain: if you did (or do) have a public domain name, you could (can) get a free cert for it from www.letsencrypt.org (via many 'clients', see https://letsencrypt.org/docs/client-options/ )